# 'last' does not include logs for few last days

Tags: osx, login, last

When I execute 'last', I do not see logs from past 6 days.
What could be the case? Is it possible to clear these logs?
I'm on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: You mean you do see logins from earlier than 6 days ago, or do you mena only those logins from 6 days ago and later?

Comment: I mean logins from earlier than 6 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file that `last` uses was probably rotated on the first of the month. I'm not familiar with OS/X, but check the manpage for the file used, and do something like:

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

to tell `last` to list the logins from the older file.